# Jagged shadows with default settings

Tags: unity, shadows

This is what it looks like no matter the settings I use when I try to use shadows in Unity. Changing the Bias or the Normal Bias does effect the shadows, but I cannot get the shadows to be smooth with any settings. Making the model bigger does fix this, but I would optimally not scale the model up, as it is already at 10.

[image: Bad Shadows]

Comment: Do you want better shadow in realtime or baked?

Comment: Either would be good, but I think that realtime would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **hard shadow** with **very high** shadow resolution. This will effect on editor as well as build.
Change quality settings levels for your intended platform. In shadow section **hard shadow only** and **very high** shadow resolution. May also increase **anti aliasing** in rendering section. These will effect on build quality.

[image]

Comment: This helped but did not solve the problem, thanks for the help though. I will post the answer below in a second.

Answer (score 4):

So it seems like while changing the quality settings did increase the quality of the shadows it did not remove the artifacts, but when I was int he QualitySettings menu, I saw some settings that I had seen in other forums. Changing the shadow distance to a lower value increased the quality of the shadows and removed the artifacts. This also allows the use of soft shadows, but the bias then needs to be increased slightly to .005.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this shadow distance remark. I was having the jagged edges problem, and it was indeed due to a very high shadow distance

Comment: Thanks , solves my problem.