# Unity - jagged shadows when export as apk?

Tags: unity, c#, shadows, virtual-reality

Alright, I found this question with the same problem but it's out of date [Jagged shadows with default settings](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/125619/jagged-shadows-with-default-settings)

My problem is a discrepancy between shadow quality settings in editor vs apk built to Oculus Quest. I don't know if VR is a factor here. I have desktop and Android set to the same default quality settings, which are determined by the same Universal Render Pipeline Asset -

[image]

In editor, shadows are nice and soft, although if you increase shadow distance they get a bit jagged -

[image]

This is exacerbated on Quest apk -

[image]

I've tried all the options and turning off shadow cascades - that just results in more spread out jaggedness. What can I do to get the highest quality soft shadows in apk built to Oculus Quest?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is almost a year old now, but I ran into a similar problem and couldn't find a lot of info. What happened for me was I just created a template scene and was testing things out and realized the controllers' shadows on the ground were extremely pixelated only when running on the headset. When in the editor they look crisp. I tried to change the settings and deleted all the quality presets except for ultra, but that didn't change anything.

What did work was when I changed the ground plane's scale from (10, 10, 10) to (1, 1, 1). Once I did that and tested the build on my headset, the shadows looked great. Probably not the best solution as it probably wouldn't work the same for the UI since it has to be scaled really high to just show up, don't know if there's any way around that. But I thought at least I'd put up some sort of solution for others who also come upon this question.